# Transition diagram using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

Can anyone please tell me how to change the direction of the highlighted arrow in 
the diagram? I spent a long time trying to do this not sure how to :(

Thank you so much!

[image: current output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations,babel,patterns,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
Circ/.style={circle, fill, minimum width=12pt},
InLineArrow/.style={
draw,thick, postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\fill(0:5pt) -- (120:5pt) -- (240:5pt);}}}}
]
%Drawing the nodes
%\node[tikzstyle, label=angle_orientation:Text](Node_coordinate_Identifier) at (position_in_polar_coordinates){Text_none};
\node[Circ, label=150:$H$](H) at (150:2.5){};
\node[Circ, label=30:$O$](O) at (30:2.5){};
\node[Circ, label=270:$R$](R) at (270:2.5){};
%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.41] (H) arc (150-180:150-180-360:0.8) node [pos=0.41, anchor=180-180,inner sep=7pt]{20\sf\%};
\draw[InLineArrow=0.58] (O) arc (30-180:30-180-360:0.8) node [pos=0.58, anchor=0-180,inner sep=7pt]{80\sf\%};
\draw[InLineArrow=0.75] (R) arc (270-180:270-180-360:0.8)node [pos=0.65, anchor=180-180,inner sep=7pt]{20\sf\%};
%
%Drawing the arrows
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (H) to [bend left=30] node[anchor=-90, inner sep=8pt]{40\sf\%} (O);
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (O) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=-90, inner sep=6pt]{10\sf\%} (H);
%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (H) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=50, inner sep=4pt]{40\sf\%} (R);
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (R) to [bend left=30] node[anchor=30, inner sep=4pt]{30\sf\%} (H);
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (O) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=180, inner sep=6pt]{10\sf\%} (R);
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (R) to [bend left=20] node[anchor=-60, inner sep=8pt]{50\sf\%} (O);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\\\\\\\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[
Circ/.style={circle, fill, minimum width=9pt},
InLineArrow/.style={
    draw,thick, postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\fill(0:5pt) -- (120:5pt) -- (240:5pt);}}}}
]
%Drawing the nodes
%\node[tikzstyle, label=angle_orientation:Text](Node_coordinate_Identifier) at (position_in_polar_coordinates){Text_none};
\node[Circ, label=-90:$A$](A) at (0,0){};
\node[Circ, label= +0:$B$](B) at (7,0){};
\node[Circ, label=+90:$C$](C) at (7,6){};
\node[Circ, label=+110:$D$](D) at (0,6){};
%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.41] (D) arc (150-180:150-180-360:0.8) node [pos=0.41, anchor=180-180,inner sep=7pt]{0.1};
%\draw[InLineArrow=0.41] (B) arc (150-180:150-180-360:0.8) node [pos=0.41, anchor=180-180,inner sep=7pt]{0.6};
%\draw[InLineArrow=0.75] (B) arc (270-180:270-180-360:0.8) node [pos=0.65, anchor=180-180,inner sep=7pt]{0.6};
\draw[InLineArrow=0.75] (B) arc (360-180-30:360-180-30-360:0.8) node [pos=0.41, anchor=180-180,inner sep=7pt]{};
\node[below] at (7.65,-1.3) {$0.6$};
%%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (A) to [bend left=30] node[anchor=+360, inner sep=+7pt]{0.3} (D);
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (D) to [bend left=30] node[anchor=+180, inner sep=+7pt]{0.9} (A);
%%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (A) to  node[anchor=+90, inner sep=+7pt]{0.7} (B);
%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (B) to [bend left=30] node[anchor=+360, inner sep=+7pt]{0.4} (C);
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (C) to [bend left=30] node[anchor=+360, inner sep=+7pt]{0.2} (B);
%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (C) to  node[anchor=+90, inner sep=+7pt]{0.8} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
\draw[InLineArrow=0.75] (B) arc (360-180-30:360-180-30-360:0.8) node [pos=0.41, anchor=180-180,inner sep=7pt]{};
```

to

```
\draw[InLineArrow=0.25] (B) arc (360-180-30:360-180-30+360:0.8) node [pos=0.41, anchor=180-180,inner sep=7pt]{};
```

The same, along with the label 0.6 can be achieved by simply writing

```
\draw[InLineArrow=0.25] (B) arc (150:150+360:0.8)node[pos=0.25,below]{0.6};
```

You can avoid these long statements, see the MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
Circ/.style={circle, fill, minimum width=9pt},
InLineArrow/.style={
    draw,thick, postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\fill(0:5pt) -- (120:5pt) -- (240:5pt);}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Drawing the nodes
\node[Circ, label=-90:$A$](A) at (0,0){};
\node[Circ, label= +0:$B$](B) at (7,0){};
\node[Circ, label=+90:$C$](C) at (7,6){};
\node[Circ, label=+110:$D$](D) at (0,6){};
%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.41] (D) arc (-30:-30-360:0.8) node[pos=0.41,left=+7pt]{0.1};
\draw[InLineArrow=0.25] (B) arc (150:150+360:0.8) node[pos=0.25,below=7pt]{0.6};
%%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (A) to [bend left=30] node[left=7pt]{0.3} (D);
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (D) to [bend left=30] node[right=7pt]{0.9} (A);
%%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (A) to  node[below=+7pt]{0.7} (B);
%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (B) to [bend left=30] node[left=+7pt]{0.4} (C);
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (C) to [bend left=30] node[left=+7pt]{0.2} (B);
%
\draw[InLineArrow=0.5] (C) to  node[below=+7pt]{0.8} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked beautifully.